# Failed to create session: 'staticmethod' object is not callable Traceback (most recent call last)

Tags: python, otree

I'm trying to solve this issue in OtreeHub,

```
Failed to create session: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/otree/session.py", line 447, in create_session_traceback_wrapper
    return create_session(**kwargs)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/otree/session.py", line 418, in create_session
    func(subsession)
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

I would like to know about how to solve this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: static methods are define by @staticmethod